# Strongswan IPSec to Amazon VPC going down randomly

Tags: networking, ipsec, strongswan, amazon-vpc

I got established connection between Amazon VPC and my site using strongswan.

I followed documentation from Amazon. Tunnel can be established and is running but is going down randomly if I can say.

Here is my ipsec.conf:

```
conn %default
        mobike=no
        compress=no
        authby=psk
        keyexchange=ikev2
        ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024!
        ikelifetime=28800s
        esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024!
        lifetime=3600s
        keyingtries=3
        rekeymargin=3m
        installpolicy=yes
        type=tunnel
        left=######(My IP)
        dpddelay=10
        dpdtimeout=3
        dpdaction=clear
        #lifetime = 300m
        #margintime = 10m
        #rekeyfuzz = 100%

conn vpc-tunnel-first
        leftsubnet=169.254.248.34,10.10.0.0/24,10.100.0.0/24
        right=177.72.241.58
        rightsubnet=169.254.248.33,10.20.0.0/24
        auto=start
```

There is nothing logged by charon when tunel goes down. Where should I look next?

Comment: you solve your problem? I have similar problem

Comment: No, I did not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Raise the charon log level (enable debug mode).

Use `tcpdump` or `tshark` to check whether *any* packets are being sent.

Use `ip xfrm state`, `ip xfrm policy`, `setkey -D (-P) -p` to check the associations that strongSwan has loaded into the kernel, make sure they haven't disappeared.

Comment: Our tunnel is working - it is up and running - sometimes for one hour sometimes for twenty minutes. What did help little bit was setting dpddelay to 3. It seems that tunnel is little bit more stable. But I cannot rely on something which is failing randomly for unknown reason. I've setuped charon debug logging but there are too many information being presented. I will setup debug logging as this: charondebug="dmn 2, mgr 2, ike 2, chd 2, job 2, cfg 2, knl 2, net 2, enc
2, lib 2" Is this sufficient?